# Convert a dict of excel sheets to DataFrames efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have used

```
my_dict = ExcelFile(xls, None)
```

to create a dictionary of excel sheets. The key being the name of the sheet. How can I use a list of the dict keys to create a df for each sheet? I tried using something like:

```
for sheet in keys:
    df_sheet = my_dict[sheet]
```

There might be an even easier function for this specific task, but in your answer can you include a way to solve it using a loop like above?

Comment: Use dictionary comprehension with [parse](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html): `df_dict = {k:my_dict.parse(k) for k,v in my_dict.items()}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) with argument `sheet_name=None`. This will return an `OrderedDict` mapping worksheet name to dataframe for all worksheets:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
```

This is mentioned a few times in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

> **sheet_name** : string, int, mixed list of strings/ints, or None, default 0
>
> Specify None to get all sheets.
>
> None -> Dict of DataFrames is returned, with keys representing sheets.
>
> None -> All sheets as a dictionary of DataFrames